# Query 1 field using 2 field for where clause

Tags: database, postgresql

i have table like this in **POSTGRESQL**:

```
Column       |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------
id           | smallint                    | not null
merchant_id  | smallint                    | not null
batch_no     | smallint                    | not null
```

i have query like this :

```
select merchant_id , max(batch_no) from batch group by merchant_id
```

it returns a value like this :

```
       merchant_id | max  
-------------------+------
                14 |  593
                45 |    1
                34 |    3
                46 |    1
                25 |  326
                27 |   61
                17 |    4
```

how i can get an id of each data? what query i can used for to get 1 result whish is the id of the data above?

Comment: it looks like you need to also pull id. in your case it would be `select id, merchant_id, max(batch_no) from batch group by merchant_id`

Comment: What is ID's relationship to merchant_ID?  Can you post the first 5 or so rows of SELECT * FROM batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query works with any version of PostgreSQL, even before there were window functions (**PostgreSQL 8.3** or earlier):

```
SELECT b.id, b.merchant_id, b.batch_no
FROM   batch b
JOIN  (
   SELECT merchant_id, max(batch_no) AS batch_no
   FROM   batch
   GROUP  BY merchant_id
   ) bmax USING (merchant_id, batch_no)
```

If `batch_no` should not be unique per `merchant_id`, you may get multiple rows per `merchant_id`.

---

With **PostgreSQL 8.4** or later you use the [window function `first_value()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       merchant_id
     , first_value(batch_no) OVER w
     , first_value(id) OVER w
FROM   batch
GROUP  BY merchant_id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY batch_no DESC, id)
```

This even yields unique rows per merchant_id if `batch_no` should not be unique. In this case the smallest `id` (for the biggest `batch_no` per `merchant_id`) would be selected as I additionally sort the window by `id`.

I use `DISTINCT` here, because it is applied *after* the window function (as opposed to `GROUP BY`).

Comment: hi erwin,, thx for your answer.. it works.. but i wanna ask 1 question about "USING" function. what is the purpose?

Comment: @DiazPradiananto: `USING` is a shorthand notation for the JOIN condition. Read the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).